# $\alpha$ is a plane curve if and only if all its osculator planes intersect at one point

Tags: geometry, differential

Let $\alpha$ be a regular curve. Prove that $\alpha$ is plane if and only if all the osculator planes intersect at one point.

I know that $\alpha$ is plane iff the binormal vector is constant, or iff the osculator plane is the same at every point. However, I don't know how to prove that.

**NOTE:** Originally, the statement said that "a curve is plane if and only if all the *tangent* planes intersect at one point". I understant that the tangent plane is the osculator plane, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Say all the osculating planes pass through the origin. This means that $$\alpha(s)=\lambda(s)T(s)+\mu(s)N(s)$$
for some functions $\lambda$, $\mu$. Now differentiate and use Frenet.

Comment: Thanks! However, I don't see why if all the osculating planes pass through the origin, then $\alpha$ can be written like that. I understand that you've written $\alpha$ as the linear combination of the basis $\{T(s), N(s), B(s)\}$, but I don't see why the coefficient of $B$ is zero.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. If the planes passes through the origin, then $\alpha(s) B(s) = 0$, so the coefficient of $B$ is zero, right?

Comment: Or, directly, a vector in the plane is a linear combination of basis vectors for the plane.

Comment: @TedShifrin, but what you people got was that the coefficient of $B$ is zero, not that it's constant. I don't see why the exercise is finished. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @SeñorBilly: We started by writing an equation interpreting the *hypotheses*, yes. Did you try differentiating the equation and substituting the Frenet formulas?

Comment: Yes, and I got, for example, that $\tau \mu$ = 0, where $\tau$ is the torsion. (I got that because $\tau \mu$ is the component of $B$). Continuing I should get that in fact $\tau$ is zero, right? I don't see how...

Comment: @SeñorBilly Great! Yes, you want $\tau=0$. What does it say if $\mu=0$ on an interval?

Comment: Awesome! $\alpha(s) = \lambda(s) T(s)$. After differentiating, and applying Frenet, if I assume that the curvature is not zero, I get that $\lambda$ must be zero, so $\alpha$ doesn't "move". Then, $\tau$ is zero in a dense. As it's continuous, it's zero. My only problem is that I assume that the curvature is not zero, and I think I've got to consider that case also.

Comment: Nevermind, of course we ask for the curvature to be non zero. If not, I think we can't even define the torsion. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, also, if $\mu=0$ in an interval, what I really get is that, as $\alpha$ doesn't move in that interval, $T = 0$, which is absurd.

Comment: No, if $\mu=0$, then $\alpha$ just moves along a line (why?), and you already said that in that case the osculating plane is not even defined.